# How to Integrate Stand Alone python scripts into django Website

Tags: python, django, git

i'm new with django so i'm not sure what i want is the best thing for django.
i have many scripts in Python that call git commands for git use.
i added a bash file for dialog system in linux just so i wont have to write the commands each time.

i want to switch the dialog menu with a website and i heard that django is the best for this as my scripts are based on python.

i dont really need a DB since its operation on a local git server.
i did a tutorial of django blog site and its not what i need.
is there a place where i can see some examples of how to do what i want?

all i need is to move my scripts to website, either to be used with buttons or drop-down list and so.

thanks

Comment: from your description I think Django would be a good choice. Otherwise try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: OK - but is there a place where i can see examples of this with Django?

Comment: django views are just python functions - you can use the library/script exactly as you are now. You can use `django.forms` to collect any information you need, then just call your methods within the view.